# Elo-aH - Feminine or not?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, mysticism-kabbalah

I had been taught that Elokim is a unification of Divine Feminine and Masculine from the root Elo-aH. Is this the case or is the Name Elo-aH also masculine?

Answer (score 1):

No.

> ּוַיִּטֹּש אֱלוֹהַּ עָשָׂהו
>
> Devarim 32:15

עשהו is masculine; the feminine version would probably be ּעָשָׂתְהו (or maybe עָשַׂתּוּ like in Rut 4:15, but anyway not עשהו).

There are other examples, like Chavakuk 3:3 and lots of places in Iyov, the first one in 3:4.

Tehillim 139:19 looks feminine at first glance, but in that mizmor David is talking to Hashem directly in the second person, so תקטל is masculine (if You, Hashem, kill the evildoer...).